# NiFi 1.10.0 - PutFile does not see the destination directory

Tags: linux, apache-nifi

We are facing a peculiar problem on one of our 2 environments. A PutFile processor throws the following error

```
PutFile[id=xxx] Penalizing StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=xxx,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=xxx, container=default, section=1012], offset=94495, length=9778],offset=0,name=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_PROD_20200513020001.json.gz,size=9778] and routing to 'failure' because the output directory /data/home/datadelivery/OUT/Test does not exist and Processor is configured not to create missing directories
```

After enabling the creation of missing directories, the error changes to:

```
Could not set create directory with permissions 664 because /data/home/datadelivery/OUT/Test: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /data/home/datadelivery/OUT/TestPutFile[id=xxx...
```

Based on the error message one would think that it is an issue with file and folder permissions, however, the path `/data/home/datadelivery/OUT/Test` exists, and the nifi user can access and create files and folders in there as well (verified from the command line). The same folder permissions and ownership rights are configured on our DEV environment, where the PutFile processor works as expected. We could change the configuration to use a different location, but I'd rather find the root cause instead.

Where should I start debugging?

Thank you for your help in advance!
Kind regards, Julius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the NiFi service solved the problem. The issue was that the Unix user (nifi) was modified months after starting the NiFi service. Most probably this was the reason the PutFile processor wasn't able to access a folder which the nifi unix user could.

Answer (score 0):

Strange issue, I would try to set full permission on the folder/file you want to write (ie chmod 777 + chown nifi:nifi + recursively), and see if the error is still there. If not it's kind of a start ...

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it does indeed work with the permissions set to 777, but we are trying to avoid that. Changing it to 777 lets the processor access the folder and put the files there, modifying the permissions back to 770 returns us to square one (NiFi claims the directory does not exist).

Comment: Agreed, that it is alway better to avoid 777 permissions. 770 should work if nifi own the folder. Maybe check the username of nifi, just to be sure it is not somethink else.